# Undefined reference to info()

Tags: c++

So basically I was given an assignment to write a program that uses three arrays, one to store the given names and the other two to output whether an Employ will be an Attendee at a conference. The employee is allowed to attend both sessions. (We are not allowed to use pointers, referencing or structs)

This is what I have written so far but I get the error:

```
undefined reference to `info(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, int, int)'
```

Any tips on how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

//Function initialization
bool info(string Names[10], int num, int pos);
void display(string Names[10], bool sesA[10], bool sesB[10]);
void totalAttendees(bool tempA[10], bool tempB[10]);

//Main program
int main() {

    //Variable declaration
    string arrNames[10] = {"Cindy Hess", "David Thornton", "Amanda Bryan", "Claudia Newton", "Heather Snyder", "Amy Rodriguez", "Kerry Ellis", "Yolanda Mccullough", "Summer Price", "Sandra Carter"};
    bool SessionA[10], SessionB[10];
    char choice, ses;
    int att, ctr, session;
    ctr = 0;

    //Input loops for SessionA & SessionB
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        SessionA[i] = info(arrNames, ctr, i);
    }
    ctr++;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        SessionB[i] = info(arrNames, ctr, i);
    }

    //While loop for editing SessionA & SessionB
    cout << "Would you like to edit a session?(Y-yes / N-no): ";
    cin >> choice;
    while (toupper(choice) == 'Y') {
        cout << "Which Attendee would you like to edit: ";
        cin >> att;
        cout << "Which Session would you like to edit(A / B): ";
        cin >> ses;
        cout << "Update session(1-accept / 2-decline): ";
        cin >> session;

        if (toupper(ses) == 'A') {

            if (session == 1) {
                SessionA[att] = true;
            }
            else if (session == 2) {
                SessionA[att] = false;
            }
        }
        else if (toupper(ses) == 'B') {

            if (session == 1) {
                SessionB[att] = true;
            }
            else if (session == 2) {
                SessionB[att] = false;
            }
        }

        cout << "Would you like to edit a session?(Y-yes / N-no): ";
        cin >> choice;
    }

    totalAttendees(SessionA, SessionB);

    return 0;
}

//Info Function
bool info (string Names, int num, int pos) {
    string s;
    bool choice;

    if (num == 0) {
        s = "SESSION A";
    }
    else if (num == 1) {
        s = "SESSION B";
    }

    cout << (pos + 1) << ". " << Names[pos] << "are they going to attend " << s << "(1-accept / 2-decline): ";
    cin >> num;

    if (num == 1) {
        choice = true;
    }
    else if (num == 2) {
        choice = false;
    }

    return choice;
}

//Display Function
void display (string Names[10], bool sesA[10], bool sesB[10]) {
    cout << "#  " << "Attendee\t\t" << "Session A\t" << "Session B" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%n. %2s %10b %5b\n", i + 1, Names[i], sesA[i], sesB[i]);
    }
}

//Total attendees function
void totalAttendees (bool sesA[10], bool sesB[10]) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (sesA[i] == true && sesB[i] == true) {
            total++;
        }
        else if (sesA[i] == true) {
            total++;
        }
        else if (sesB[i] == true) {
            total++;
        }
    }
    cout << "The total Attendees: " << total;
}
```

Comment: As the error states, you need to define `bool info(string Names[10], int num, int pos);`.  You wrote one function named `info`, but not the one with that signature.

Comment: `bool info (string Names, int num, int pos) ` the Names variable is a single string not an array of 10 like the declaration.

Comment: Copy-paste the two declarations (from the original forward declaration and from the definition) so one is on the line above or below the other. That makes it very easy to compare them and find your error.

Comment: Also, enable more warnings when building. You code have other problems,, two which will lead to *undefined behavior* and likely crashes. I recommend you build with at least `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`. As a hint: Don't use the old C function `printf`, use the type-safe standard C++ `std::cout` stream for your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing this - [10] in your function definition.

```
//Info Function
bool info(string Names[10], int num, int pos) {
 ...
}
```